# How to allow workstations to see printer fonts on shared printer?

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

I recently upgraded a small company's computers. The new computers did not have parallel port cards so I bought a few parallel to USB adapters. These work fine on the local workstation, but if I then share the workstation and another workstation attempts to print via this printer, it doesn't see/use the printer fonts. Is there a way to correct this other than getting a parallel port card or replacing the printer with a newer model?

Comment: If the printer's only connection option is a parallel port...I would replace the printer.  With a networked one so you don't need to deal with sharing from the workstations.

Comment: Printer fonts are still a thing?!?

Comment: I know, I know - these are impact printers (dot matrix) used for making carbon copies when printing invoices, tickets, etc. They are used in industrial settings where high reliability in poor working conditions is required.